# Prevent user from navigating directly to a page in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is there a way to prevent users from navigating directly to a page in Silverlight 4? 
Thank you.

Comment: please explain your question a little more.

Comment: I have a silverlight navigation application with many pages, there is a particular page that needs to be navigated to via another page. I don't want users to be able to get to this page directly either by bookmarking or entering the url in the address bar. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the [Page.OnNavigatingFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method and cacel the navigation before it happens.